# What is the Parse Table View default sorting method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, parse-platform

**I'm using `Parse` `PFQueryTableViewController`, and was wondering if anyone knew what the default method in which results were sorted/put into the table view was?**

Without doing anything, by data comes into the table view like this, and I'm not sure what it is sorting by (doesn't seem to be by `test` or `dateTime`:

[image]

Here is my `Parse` data:

[image]

Here is my `ViewController.m`:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];
    if (self) {
        self.parseClassName = @"na";
        self.textKey = @"dateTime";
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;
        self.paginationEnabled = NO;
    }
    return self;
}
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable
{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];

    return query;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"RecipeCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    UILabel *homeLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:101];
    homeLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"test"];

    UILabel *dateLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:102];
    dateLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"dateTime"];

    return cell;
}
```

Any ideas? I can add any extra information as needed. Thanks!

**EDIT:** 
I added `[query orderByDescending:@"dateTime"];` which gave me this:

[image]

So then I saw it didn't know how to order both April 19 because it probably wasn't in proper date format for it to know, so I tested by changing that to:

[image]

So it looks like I'll need to change all of them to that, but I'm wondering since I'll want the date format to look different than that if I'll need to do that on the `Parse query` side of things -OR- do it once I get my `Parse query` data in my `ViewController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PFQTVC autonomously sets the default to descending chronological order. See the notes here in the 'Customizing the Query' section:

> The default query is set to get objects from your class ordered by descending createdAt. To customize, simply override the queryForTable method to return your own PFQuery. The table will use this query when getting objects to display.

**REFERENCE** : https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#ui-tables/iOS

Comment: Ah I see.  I added some info to my question per your response, would I need to format the date on the 'Parse query` side of things, or would I format the date once I get the `Parse query` back?  Thanks!!

Comment: No problem @SRMR it would be helpful to understand what your trying to do first. So please update you question with that and I'll help you. It's generally a bad idea to use strings for numbers and here's why, say you have 1-200. And you want to order it ascending, well naturally you get 1-99 in order right. But as soon as you hit 100 this is what your order will look like: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,100,11,12,13,14,15...etc since technically 100 as a string comes before 11. So my suggestion would be to use the date column type instead of a string and it will make your life ten times easier

Comment: @SRMR actually it would be poor SO etiquette if you ask two questions within the same question. I suggest creating a new question with your issue that way future question seekers with the same problem have an easier way to find it. I doubt users will search through comments to find it.